solution-verification | ind the measures of the angles $(AD',A'M)$ and $((A'MN),(ABC))$
The problem
Consider the cube $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ with $M$ in the middle of $BC$ and $N$ in the middle of $DC$. Find the measures of the angles $(AD',A'M)$ and $((A'MN),(ABC))$
My solution
drawing

For the first angle we can easily see that $AD' || BC'$ which means $\angle (AD',A'M)=\angle (BC',A'M)$
Because $BCC'B'$ is a square, then we have $M$ the centre of it and $B'M \perp BC'$ and we also know that $A'B' \perp (BCC'B')$ so we can apply the theorem of the 3 perpendicular and get that $A'M \perp BC'$ so $\angle (AD', A'M)=\angle (BC', A'M)=90$
For the second angle, I let $P\in BC, MP \perp BC$ and we can see that P is the midpoint of BC.
The I let another point $A'M \cap AP={Q}$ and because $MP || AA'$ and $2MP=AA'$ we get that $MP$ is a midline in triangle $A'QA$
So we get that $P$ is also the midpoint of $AQ$ so we can demonstrate that CQBA is a parallelogram.
Because $CQ||AB$ and $DC||AB$ we get that $D,C,Q$ are collinear so because we know that $(A'MN) \cap (ABC)$, $A'D \perp DC, AD \perp DC$ means that $\angle((A'MN),(ABC))=\angle (A'D,AD)=\angle A'DA=45$
Im not sure if this part is correct because i never did this in a problem to solve it so i wanna make sure if its corect,,The I let another point $A'M \cap AP={Q}$ and because $MP || AA'$ and $2MP=AA'$ we get that MP is a midline in triangle $A'QA$ So we get that P is also the midpoint of AQ so we can demonstrate that CQBA is a parallelogram. Because $CQ||AB$ and $DC||AB$ we get that $D,C,Q$ are collinear"
Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

I. That the first angle is $90^o$ can also be seen as follows:
As OP observes, $\angle (AD’,A’M)=\angle (BC’,A’M)$.
Join $A’B$.
If the side of the cube is $1$, then since$$A’B=\sqrt 2$$and$$BM=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$$and by Pythagoras$$AM=\sqrt {1^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\right)^2}=\sqrt\frac{3}{2}$$

it follows that$$A’B^2=BM^2+A’M^2$$and hence$$\angle A'MB=90^o$$
II. For the second angle, join $MN$, $AN$, and $A’D$.
$\angle ((A’MN,ABC))=\angle ((A’MN,AND))$. And since the angle of two planes is the angle between perpendiculars to their common section, and $ND$ is perpendicular to both $AD$ and $A’D$, then$$\angle ((A’MN,ABC))=\angle ((A’MN,AND)=\angle A’DA=45^o$$

Thank you so much for your answer! Soo...as I understand my solution is ok?

It seems $D,C,Q$ are collinear by construction and so don’t need proof.  Your solution works, but do you need to bring in point $P$, lines $APQ$, $A’MQ$, $MP$, and parallelogram $CQBA$?  It’s often good, and sometimes necessary, to “think outside the box,” but here why not stay inside it?
